# Printing YouTube Video Titles to File w/Selenium & Python, MacOS

Tags: python, macos, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to create a basic web scraper that takes input from the user to search for a video on YouTube and then write x number of titles to a file. I have tried using the ID of the video title, XPATH, and CSS_SELECT0R but am unable to get the program to fully do what I am wanting it to. I either get stuck in the automated browser (it doesn't quit) or I am unable to write the web element to the file. This is my current code:

```
# Importing the necessary modules for the program to run.
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium import webdriver

# This is the first part of the program. It asks the user for a search query and how many results they
# want to see.
request = input('Search for: ')
split_request = request.split()
url = 'https://www.Youtube.com/results?search_query=' + '+'.join(split_request) + '+'
query_amount = int(input('How many results do you want to see? '))
driver = webdriver.Safari()
actions = ActionChains(driver)
driver.get(url)
i = 0

# Creating a new file called 'YouTube Search Results.txt' and opening it in write mode.
with open('YouTube Search Results.txt', mode='w') as file:
    pass
try:
    # Waiting for the elements with the ID 'video-title' to load.
    WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]/yt-formatted-string/text()')))
    # This is the part of the program that scrolls down the page to load more results.
    query = (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]/yt-formatted-string/text()'))
    while i < query_amount:
        actions.scroll_by_amount(0, 10)
        query = (driver.find_elements(By.XPATH, '//*[@id="video-title"]/yt-formatted-string/text()'))
        i = len(query)        
    # Counting the number of results and breaking the loop when the number of results is greater than
    # the amount of results the user wants to see.
        count = 0
    for title in query:
        if count > query_amount:
            break
        # This is the part of the program that writes the results to the file.
        else:
            count += 1
            with open('YouTube Search Results.txt', mode='a') as file:
                file.write(title.text + '\n')
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

I believe the issue is in the last block but I am unable to figure it out.
Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: I personally recommend you `pytube` library instead of selenium

Comment: Looking for such kind of tutorials https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vuaApmJW6Yo&list=UUsFz0IGS9qFcwrh7a91juPg&index=36

Comment: This one should be helpful  https://youtu.be/lTypMlVBFM4